# illegal escape character on BuildConfig.java, Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-idea, android-build, android-buildconfig

I Clone a [project](https://github.com/mendhak/gpslogger) using Android studio 2.2.2 on windows, when I run the project there is an error

**illegal escape character** on the BuildConfing.java file

The original development might be used IntelliJ IDEA on linux ubutu. 
I did clean the project and rebuild it, no changes.

The error is on the following line

```
public static final String[] TRANSLATION_ARRAY = new String[]  {"G:\Developer\AndroidStudioProjects\gpslogger\gpslogger\src\main\res\values","G:\Developer.......,....,....};
```

BuildConfig.java is an Auto generated file and should not be edited.

Why is this happen? how BuildConfig.java is generated ?

**UPDATE**

@Vijai, Thanks a lot. 
the problem is on the build.gradle file. 
following task returns a string with illegal escape character.

```
task buildTranslationArray << {
def foundLocales = new StringBuilder()
foundLocales.append("new String[]{")

fileTree("src/main/res").visit { FileVisitDetails details ->
    if(details.file.path.endsWith("strings.xml")){
        def languageCode = details.file.parent.tokenize('/').last().replaceAll('values-','').replaceAll('-r','-')
        languageCode = (languageCode == "values") ? "en" : languageCode;
        foundLocales.append("\"").append(languageCode).append("\"").append(",")
    }
}
foundLocales.append("}")
//Don't forget to remove the trailing comma
def foundLocalesString = foundLocales.toString().replaceAll(',}','}')
android.defaultConfig.buildConfigField "String[]", "TRANSLATION_ARRAY", foundLocalesString
}
preBuild.dependsOn buildTranslationArray
```

How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

## Update

Sorry I did not read that the issue is with `BuildConfig`. While it is true that its **not adviced** to edit BuildConfig.java, its contents do come somewhere from `build.gradle` and you have to escape character there

---

The charcter `\` is a special character and needs to be escaped. replace all instance of `\` by `\\` like

```
public static final String[] TRANSLATION_ARRAY = new String[]  {"G:\\Developer\\AndroidStudioProjects\\gpslogger\\gpslogger\\src\\main\\res\\values","G:\\Developer.......,....,....};
```

Comment: Yes I know, I have to replace all instance of  ' \ ' by ' \\ '. But the problem is BuildConfig.java file is auto **generated**, We should **not edit** the file, and cannot edit it.

Comment: While it is true you are **not supposed to edit** BuildConfig.java, the `TRANSLATION_ARRAY` comes somewhere from build.gradle. So that would be the location where you have to escape the character. Updated the answer